# Filter a null column out of tuple in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am working on a usecase where we have to eliminate the nulls out of a tuple

```
    A =
    (7,Ron,ron@abc.com)
    (8,,rina@xyz.com )
    (9,Don,)
    (9,Don,dmes@xyz.com)
    (10,Maya,maya@cnn.com)



    B = FILTER A BY col2 != '';
```

Output :-

```
    (7,Ron,ron@abc.com)
    (9,Don,dmes@xyz.com)
    (10,Maya,maya@cnn.com)
```

Here the filter operator filters the second row. But we have to filter the column.

The expected output should be something like:

```
(7,Ron,ron@abc.com)
(8,rina@xyz.com)
(9,Don,dmes@xyz.com)
(9,Don)
(10,Maya,maya@cnn.com)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can split our relation into sub relations, project desired columns, then union the result together :
So if the first column is not nullable, the second and the third are nullable but always we have atleast one of them, then :

```
SPLIT A INTO col1null IF $1 is null, col2null  IF $2 is null, allnotnull IF ($1 is not null AND $2 is not null);
col1reject = FOREACH col1null GENERATE $0,$2; --remove column $1
col2reject = FOREACH col2null GENERATE $0,$1; --remove column $2
OUT = UNION allnotnull ,col1reject , col2reject ;
```

Comment: `A = LOAD 'emp' USING PigStorage('|') AS (col1:chararray, col2:chararray,col3:chararray);
SPLIT A INTO X IF col2 != '', Y IF col2 == '';
Y2 = FOREACH Y GENERATE $0,$1; 
OUT = UNION X, Y2;
DUMP OUT;

Still i get : 

(7,Ron,ron@abc.com)
(9,Don,dmes@xyz.com)
(9,Don,dmes@xyz.com)
(10,Maya,maya@cnn.com)
`

Comment: @sandyyyy Can you please dump `X` and `Y` ?

Comment: `dump X;
(7,Ron,ron@abc.com)
(9,Don,dmes@xyz.com)
(9,Don,dmes@xyz.com)
(10,Maya,maya@cnn.com)


dump Y;


<Y is empty >`

Comment: Here is the output i got : `(7,Ron,ron@abc.com)
(9,Don,dmes@xyz.com)
(9,Don,dmes@xyz.com)
(10,Maya,maya@cnn.com)
(8,)`

Comment: @sandyyyy Updated, please try it